# use variable in function T-sql Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi everyone i have a table named matale(nom varchar,prenom varchar,departement(varchar) )
and what i want is to have for each column a table having for each distinct value of the column the number of occurence of this value .
To do this i have have this function :

```
create function countnumberoccurenceofcolumn( @column varchar(20),@limit int )
 returns @tab table ( modalite varchar(20) , occurence int)
as
begin
Insert into @tab select  @column,count(@column) as occurence from matable group  by     @column,departement
return 
end
go
```

but i have this error :

```
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not grouping by anything - your group by statement needs to include a column name that isn't a math operator but is in the select list. I,e:

```
select department, count(department) as occurence 
from matable group by departement
```

Group By allows you to collect items together and combine them together under a maths operator. So, for instance given this data in "MyTable":

```
ID  Value
1   Hello
2   Hello
3   Goodbye
```

Then running this query

```
SELECT Value, COUNT(*) from MyTable GROUP BY Value
```

Would result in:

```
Hello    2
Goodbye  1
```

Your query contains nothing apart from the COUNT operator. So either you don't need a GROUP BY, or you need to include another column in your SELECT and GROUP statements.

EDIT:

If you need to do this dynamically, you need to build up a string and execute it using dynamic sql. So:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(999)

set @sql = 'Insert into @tab select ' + @column + ', count(' + @column + ') as occurence from    
matable group by ' +  @column + ',departement'

exec @sql
```

However, I don't believe your query (or your function) will work as written. Hopefully this is enough information to set you on your way.

Comment: Thanks Matt but i cannot grouping dynamically by the column name passing in parameter to the function

Comment: Thanks solved my issue using a procedure and dynamic parameter